# Gmail temporary error

Tags: gmail, email

I deleted 2000+ emails manually for my Gmail and got blocked and left a message like this:

> We’re sorry, but your Gmail account is temporarily unavailable. We apologize for the inconvenience and suggest trying again in a few minutes. You can view the G Suite Status Dashboard for the current status of the service.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

As end-user, just follow the instructions on the message.

If after an hour or so the error still happens, repeat and follow again the instructions

If after several hours the error still happens, post a question on http://support.google.com/mail/community